# Power Query or DAX - Count number of times a value is present in a column

Tags: excel, count, powerpivot, powerquery

I have a table and column A has IDs. I would like to count how many times each ID is present in the column so it would hopefully look something like this:

Column A IDs    Column B Count
1               1
12              4
10              1
12              4
12              4
36              2
36              2
12              4

I know how to do this in Excel but I am trying to do this in Power Query and/or Power Pivot.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a calculated column in powerpivot with this formula:

=CALCULATE(counta(Table[ID]),filter(Table[ID]=EARLIER(Table[ID])))

Answer (score 2):

In Power Query you can use Group By. The default UI action for Group By on the ID column will do this. The M formula will look like this:

`Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"IDs"}, {{"Count", each Table.RowCount(_), type number}})`